# C++ compiler error in netbeans

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, mingw

I've tried everything from reading the Netbeans help to browsing Google.
This code works fine in **Dev-Cpp** but not **Netbeans 6.5.1**.  Netveans also places and exclamation mark next to `#include <iostream>` which i checked and is in the include path of netbeans and is in the include folder:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Test"  << "\n";
    return (0);
}
```

My build tools are set to:

Family:  `MinGW`

**Base Directory**: `C:\Dev-Cpp\bin`

**C Compiler**: `C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\gcc.exe`

**C++ Compiler**:  `C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\g++.exe`

**Fortran Compiler**: `C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\g77.exe`

**Make Command**: `C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\make.exe`

**Debugger Command**:  `C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\gdb.exe`

I get error:

```
Running "C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\make.exe  -f Makefile CONF=Debug" in C:\Documents and Settings\Babiker\Desktop\Temp\Test

! was unexpected at this time.

C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\make.exe: *** [.validate-impl] Error 255


Build failed. Exit value 2.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cause of the error is that Netbeans is incompatible with MinGW's make.

You have a choice of supported make versions:

- Cygwin's make. [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) is a blessing. It brings as much Unix to Windows as you'd like.
- MinGW's own [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys), which "is a collection of GNU utilities such as bash, make, gawk and grep to allow building of applications and programs which depend on traditionally UNIX tools to be present". It is also a much smaller download than Cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

MinGW make tool in not compatible with NetBeans. Use msys make tool instead.

When you choose to use the make tool from msys, please be carefull to be installed in a path without spaces.

For example C:\Program Files\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make will fail. A good choice would be C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you to use codeblocks compiler for netbeans i hope this will help you

there is only a easy method to configure netBeans is first you download and install Code::Blocks IDE from [Code::Blocks IDE Downlowd](http://space.dl.sourceforge.net/project/codeblocks/Binaries/10.05/Windows/codeblocks-10.05mingw-setup.exe) and [MSYS 1.0.11](http://space.dl.sourceforge.net/project/mingw/MSYS/BaseSystem/msys-core/msys-1.0.11/MSYS-1.0.11.exe)

all setting will automatically configured

but one thing you have to

select is make command

from

C:\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe
[image]

i hope this help for you

Answer (score 0):

This may be irrelevant but you do have your make environment associated with the correct filetypes?  So it's not trying to compile a .cpp file with the normal c-compiler or anything like that?  I've never used your environment, but something like that is always possible I'd think.

And on that note, your code is IN a .cpp file, and not a .c file?  Or maybe you have it in a .cxx file (I've seen that before for C++, rare, but I've seen it), and .cxx isn't associated with C++, so it "defaults" to C for unknown types?

Maybe seeing your makefile will also help offer some insight.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running this code in netbeans 6.5 and it worked fine.
I do not understand from the question how exclamation mark was added.

I suggest checking the linker options to ensure that netbeans is linking correctly to C++ standard library.

You can find this option by right click on project file -> properties.