# NetBeans strange error

Tags: netbeans

I installed MinGW, and I'm trying to setting it on NetBeans to develop on C/C++.
Well, when I try to compile the source, (I do a clean and build) it gives me this error:

> make.exe": *** [.validate-impl] Error 53
>
> BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 364ms)

These are my settings on NetBeans for C/C++:

```
C Compiler: C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
C++ Compiler: C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe
Assembler: C:\MinGW\bin\as.exe
Make Command: C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe
Debugger Command: C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ compiler error in netbeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854681/c-compiler-error-in-netbeans)

Comment: You should also make sure `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin` is on your path.